# Python - How to get this value outside of the function with Tkinter in the way

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to take the summation variables out of the math function and return it back into the `__init__` function but i am having problems

When i add self to the save_values parameters inside the parenthesis and add self. to the Y_PRED variable inside of save_values it allows me to make an object with the Y_PRED number inside of it which is what I want. But the problem occurs when the Button function is called for the section of command = save_values. When i change it to command = save_values(self) it returns a blank array before I could even have a chance to run the save_values function. I can't think of ways to circumvent this after spending many hours on it.

code is below,

```
class Test():
def __init__(self):
    num1 = .01
    num2 = 2
    plot([summation1][summation2])

def math(self):
    summation1 = anum1+anum2
    summation2 = anum1+(anum2/2)
    return summation
```

Comment: if `save_values()` is part of your class it needs to be `save_values(self)` at the very least.

Comment: There is a lot of code here not related to your problem. Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

By using

```
command = save_values(self)
```

You're actually calling `save_values` at Button instantiation time. To pass the method in as a callback, do:

```
command = self.save_values
```

Comment: that solved that issue but created another one.. when i place this code inside the __init__ function it causes a "maximum recursion depth exceeded" where do i place it to get Y_PRED value generated from the save_values function into the __init__ function? : #        prediction = Niagara(parent,controller)
#        prediction = prediction.Y_PRED

Comment: @Dane,I'm a bit unclear on the first part of the comment. For the second part, `save_values()` doesn't get run until the given button is pressed. `__init__()` simply handles initialization of your class instance, which, of course, happens before the button can be pressed. I think what you're describing is making `Y_PRED` an instance variable of your class. You can do this by adding `self.Y_PRED = y_pred2` in `save_values()`. You probably will also want to add `self.Y_PRED = None` in `__init__()`, just for consistency.

Comment: I did this but it still did not fix the recursion error because i need to put y_pred variable values into the __init__ function from the save_values function, i created a sample of what I want to do in the main question if you could kindly review the updated code. The goal in the revised simplified code is to plot summation1 and summation 2 using the math inside of math function. I can't seem to figure out a way around not needing the plot function inside the __init__ function.

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense now. `num1` and `num2` aren't used. `summation1` and `summation2` aren't defined. This is a different question...